# How can I keep columns that contain a certain string value within their body?

Tags: r

So I've been trying to figure out how to subset a dataframe where if there is a specific string within a column, it keeps those columns and drops all others. In this case, I'm searching for 'other' and would like to go from this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| other | one | two | three |
| one | other | two | three |
| two | three | one | other |

to this:

| A | B | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| other | one | three |
| one | other | three |
| two | three | other |

I know how to filter by using the column names, but not on what is included within their cells.
Is there a neat way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   D
other   one two three
one other   two three
two three   one other", header = TRUE)

d %>%
  select_if(~any(.x == "other"))

# A     B     D
# 1 other   one three
# 2   one other three
# 3   two three other
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `map_lgl` from `purrr` package.

`map_lgl` loops through every column applying the lambda function passed as the formula: `~ any(. == 'other'))`.

`~` is short notation for `function(.x)` and `.` represents `.x`.

The output will be a logical vector that we can use to subset `df`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   D
other   one two three
one other   two three
two three   one other", header = TRUE)

df[, map_lgl(df, ~ any(. == 'other'))]
#>       A     B     D
#> 1 other   one three
#> 2   one other three
#> 3   two three other
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>